# Форматирование списка регуляркой на JS

Tags: sed, markdown

Есть такой вот список:

```
-------------------------------------------------

Studio name:
  Awesome Work 1
  Awesome Work 2
  Awesome Work 3

-------------------------------------------------

Another Studio:
  Film

-------------------------------------------------

TV Giant:
  Item 1.1
  Item 1.2
  Item 1.3

  Item 2.1
  Item 2.2

-------------------------------------------------
```

Решел перевести его на язык `markdown` таким вот образом:

```
### Studio Name
* Awesome Work 1
* Awesome Work 2
* Awesome Work 3

### Another Studio
* Film

### TV Giant
* Item 1.1
* Item 1.2
* Item 1.3
>
* Item 2.1
* Item 2.2
```

Вручную делать лень - решил программу написать, однако очень быстро понял, что моих знаний в регулярках недостаточно даже чтобы убрать горизонтальные разделительные линии (`---`).

Написал так: `result = result.replace(/\n?-{3,}\n?/g, "")`, но этот код заменяет все `---`, т.е. даже такие: `abc-------abc` => `abcabc`.

И если с оглавленим списка я ещё более менее понимаю, как его можно форматировать (хотя и не знаю, что писать), то вот как обработать элементы списка, тем более, когда там 2 и более групп - понятия не имею.

Помогите, если не решением, то советом.

Comment: Для чего нужно конвертировать список посредством JavaScript в Markdown, когда существуют различные текстовые процессоры?

Comment: Просто изначально я его писал в обычном `.txt` файле. Со временем информации стало больше, вот и подумал, как бы это всё перевести в более удобный для чтения вид. В сторону WP, конечно, смотрел, но, честно говря, хз. А на `javascript`'е лишь потому, что я только его и знаю из ЯП.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Произвести нужные изменения можно при помощи потокового текстового редактора `sed`. Команда:

```
sed -r -i.back -e '/^[-]{1,}$/d; /^\s+/s/^\s+(.+)$/* \1/; /(^\s*$|^\*)/!s/^/### /;' [PATH_TO_YOUR_TXT_FILE]
```

Приведенная команда сохранит исходный файл с расширением .bac